# How can I make My realm object synchronized?

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I import realm mobile plateform android demo app  [from realm website](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/android-demo-app/) and update these lines with my remote realm mobile plateform server adress.

```
public static final String AUTH_URL = "http://my_server_ip_adress:9080/auth";
public static final String REALM_URL = "realm://my_server_ip_adress:9080/~/realmtasks";
```

After these, I run the app and put admin realm mobile plateform credentials. I log in successful but when I create tasks on two devices running the same app, data are not synchronizing.

Please take a look at pictures below.

Find also some screenshot of the server log.
[image: Server Log]

[image: Server log]

[image: Server log]

[image: Login Screen]

[image: Adding task]

The configuration yml file is also [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7x5o8b3sers4ius/realm%20object%20server%20configuration%20yml.txt?dl=0)

Please help.

Comment: You need to make sure your username is in the format of an email address, like `blah@blah.com` or something

Comment: Morning @EpicPandaForce . Yes my username is xxxx@gmail.com. I log in successfuly with these credentials when running the demo app. But the synchronization still not working when I add task in differences devices running the same app with the same realm mobile plateform server config.

Comment: Please help Realm mobile plateform users.

Comment: I am not a Realm person, don't forget - and I do not know why your Realm server is not working. I'm not sure if your ports are right, though.

Comment: @scalp007 Could you post the server logs?

Comment: Thank you @teotwaki for your response. I have edit my question with screenshot of my server log. Since I post this question I still have the problem. I will be verry glad if I found solution.

Comment: Configuration yml file is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/7x5o8b3sers4ius/realm%20object%20server%20configuration%20yml.txt?dl=0

Comment: @scalp007 Are those the entire logs? It doesn't show any client connection. Sounds like you have a networking issue. Can you try accessing the dashboard from the device on which you run the app?

Comment: Hi @teotwaki . I do not have networking issue. I can access to my dashboard successfully on all devices I run the app. On my genyMotion emulator and my Samsung Galaxy S6 edge. Take a look at screenshot here https://www.dropbox.com/s/244qaph5wahmzgp/Screenshot_20170227-183952.png?dl=0 . Thank you for your response and sorry for the late.

Comment: I'll still need logs that show client connections to be able to help you :) Maybe you could provide the client-side logs?

Comment: Please @teotwaki . What do you mean by client connections and client-side logs?

Comment: The client SDK for sync produces logs (you'll have to look at the Android SDK documentation on how to find that, I'm a backend engineer ;)), which indicates when connections are established, data is synced, etc. This is the information that I need. When referring to "client connections", I meant that the server logs don't show any connections coming from clients on your S6. This would show up as `sync-server: Connection[x]: Connection from zz.zz.zz.zz:yyyy`